# Force the browser to download a file that has been retrieved via an external URL in PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, response, response-headers

I have been stuck on this for hours. Maybe my mind is tired. I hope someone can assist me. I am developing a Laravel application which connects to an external application that creates and edits invoices. One of my routes is supposed to allow a user to download a PDF invoice from this external application. My controller resembles the code below:

```
public function download(Invoice $invoice)
{
    // Creates an instance of the remote invoice
    $remoteInvoiceFile = RemoteInvoiceSoftware::find($invoice->id);

    return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($remoteInvoiceFile ) {
        // This calls the remote server and the server responds with the PDF file contents
        $file = $remoteInvoiceFile->download();

        echo $file;
    }, 'file.pdf');
}
```

I read about the `streamDownoad` function from the Laravel documentation and implemented it the same way it was displayed. But I am getting an error where I am able to download a PDF file, however, not only is the file less than 5KB (the original invoice file is about 60KB), I also get an error when I try to open it. Something about the file being corrupt or not parsed well.

When I `echo $remoteInvoiceFile->download()` without using the `streamDownload` I get something like this:

[image: When I echo contents of the response from the invoice URL]

Please help me figure what's going on and how I can fix this. Thank you!!

Comment: `$file $remoteInvoiceFile ->download();` does not even look like valid PHP syntax …!?!

Comment: _“Something about the file being corrupt or not parsed well.”_ - have you tried to open the dowloaded file in a text editor, and checked what it contains - whether there are any PHP errors/warnings in there?

Comment: @CBroe, I wrote this in a hurry. Apologies. I've fixed the syntax errors. Thanks. Taking a look at the output using a text editor and I cant see any errors or warnings.